# Updating app for breaking change (non-threaded comments)

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-apps

Here is the notification I just received:

App, is currently using the following deprecated features:
Non-threaded comments. Please see the developer roadmap for more details about this change.

I looked all over the API and the developer roadmap and the settings but found no way to fix this issue. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My hunch would be that they send out alerts based on the permissions your app uses - my app doesn't interact with any "comments" connections in the graph, but it does have the "publish_stream" and "manage_pages" permissions.

If someone knows otherwise please advise...

Answer (score 2):

I have received the same notification for one of my apps. My app definitely does not read or create comments on Facebook posts or objects (Facebook rolled out the threaded comments Feature in April). Thus Facebook's message is not relevant to every app they send it to.

The change should only affect apps which read or publish comments.

Here is the link to the API documentation about comments:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/

Answer (score 1):

Look at the settings page, in the "Migrations" section. Enable "July 2013 Breaking Changes" and your notification should have a green sign notifying: Your app, *appname*, is now compliant with the July 2013 Breaking Changes migration. No further action is required.

Be sure to read the complete roadmap at https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/.

Comment: By enabling the migration, does it automatically fix my non-threaded comments problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have got the following message too:

MyApp, is currently using the following deprecated features:

- The 'page_id' field in the checkin FQL table. Please use 'target_id' instead.
- The 'version' field in the group FQL Table and on the Graph API.
- Non-threaded comments. Please see the developer roadmap for more details about this change.

I am sure that in my case the warning derives from my Graph API Explorer and
my Django test code.
That means that Facebook logs every request sent by your App and send you a warning even if you used deprecated features only once.
Check it out

Comment: Do you know maybe what I have to meet the requirements of first point ('page_id' -> 'target_id')? I was searching in my code and I can find directly query to this field. I looked to Facebook SDK as well, but I cound't find it neither.

Comment: I meant "I can't find directly..."